# Laravel 5 redirect to controller actions

Tags: laravel-5

If I want to redirect to a controller's action. Must this controller action be registered in `routes.php` ?

Comment: This is a little broad, and there are two big answers from this question - depending on context.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to use a redirection like this:

```
return redirect()->action('AnotherController@someMethod');
```

This action has to be registered in the routes.php file.

But be careful: It only works with GET routes reliable.

You can see you available actions by typing

```
php artisan route:list
```

in your terminal.

I have set up some files for testing purposes (seems like laravel is redirecting to available GET methods with same parameter signature, when trying to redirect to non-get methods :

```
// routes.php

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

Route::get('start', 'TestController@start');



// routes, we could redirect to

// get route
Route::get('test', 'AnotherController@test');

// post route
Route::post('testPost', 'AnotherController@testPost');


// setup a resource with index, store, update, delete and show actions
Route::resource('resource', 'AnotherController');


});
```

A Test Controller, that is used for redirecting

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function start()
    {

        // works
        return redirect()->action('AnotherController@test');

        // method not allowed exception
        return redirect()->action('AnotherController@testPost');


        /**
         *  Redirecting to routes setup via Route::resource
         */

        // works
        return redirect()->action('AnotherController@index');

        // redirects to 'AnotherController@index'
        return redirect()->action('AnotherController@store');


        // error: Missing required parameters for [Route: resource.destroy] [URI: resource/{resource}].
        return redirect()->action('AnotherController@destroy');

        // redirects to 'AnotherController@show'
        return redirect()->action('AnotherController@destroy', 1);

        // Missing required parameters for [Route: resource.update] [URI: resource/{resource}].
        return redirect()->action('AnotherController@update');

        // redirects to 'AnotherController@show'
        return redirect()->action('AnotherController@update', 1);
    }
}
```

Another Controller, I am redirecting to:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class AnotherController extends Controller
{
    public function test()
    {
        dd('i am test');
    }

    public function testPost()
    {
        dd('i am testPost');
    }


    /**
     *  Resourceful routes below
     */

    public function index()
    {
        dd ('I am index');
    }


    public function store()
    {
        dd ('I am store');
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        dd('I am destroy');
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        dd('I am show');
    }

    public function update($id)
    {
        dd('I am update');
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `routes.php` file must contain details about the URL and Controller / Action:

```
// Get route
Route::get('/page', 'MyController@action');
// Post route
Route::post('/login', 'LoginController@login');
```

Comment: redirecting to post routes won't work properly ( assuming you are using redirect()->action()

Comment: I was just showing examples of what the ```routes.php``` file would contain, since thats what was asked, the question didn't specifically ask how the redirection should be done.